# AndroidX espresso tests not running, Tried a sample app and can make it work, not on a scaled project with many modules

Tags: android-espresso, androidx, test-runner

I have a scaled project that has at least 12 modules. I would like to start the app module and run the project. 
Every time I try to start it, I keep getting the message that

```
$ adb shell CLASSPATH=$(pm path androidx.test.services) app_process / androidx.test.services.shellexecutor.ShellMain am instrument -r -w -e targetInstrumentation *** ... *** androidx.test.orchestrator/androidx.test.orchestrator.AndroidTestOrchestrator
Client not ready yet..
Started running tests
Test running failed: No test results.
```

I read through the AndroidX documentation of espresso usage and have

- included the ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR
- have included the required
  libraries using the useLibrary function
- set up the test runner to use androidx-testRunner.

I was able to generate the tests using the Espresso test runner but every time I try to run it, I get this message. Just to be sure I made a sample app and tested the whole thing out and I am able to make instrumentation tests on the sample app.

Does anyone know what could happen in a multi-module project that uses dependency injection?

Comment: same conditions. in my case update androidx.test:orchestrator from 1.1.0 to 1.2.0 helped

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It had nothing to do with modules or project size, removing the `ANDROIDX_TEST_ORCHESTRATOR` made it work.